# How to combine Phaser 3 gravity and drag?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I need a Phaser 3 sprite to fall and bounce vertically according to gravity. I also want the body to decrease speed horizontally when the player releases the controller.

But it seems that gravity and friction don't work well together...?
As soon as I add damping and drag, gravity gets screwed up completely. Either the sprite falls very very slowly, or gravity is just removed completely.

How do I combine horizontal drag with vertical gravity?

Physics settings

```
    this.body.setBounce(1, 1)
    this.body.allowGravity = true // only works without drag/damping
    this.body.allowDrag = true
    this.body.useDamping = true
    this.body.setDrag(0.88, 0.95) // x drag and y drag
```

Controls

```
    if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
        this.body.setVelocityX(-300)
    }
    else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
        this.body.setVelocityX(300)
    }

    if (this.cursors.up.isDown) {
        this.body.setVelocityY(-300)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your drag numbers might just be too small.  At 0.95 and 60fps I think you're going to come to a complete stop in .5 seconds.  Try 0.99 or 0.999 and work your way down from there.

Comment: But the problem is it disables the gravity effect. The character just moves down very slowly but it's not accelerating like it does when gravity is working.

Comment: i'm sure if the drag is too strong will look like there is no gravity.  Did changing the numbers not work?  Also, damping and drag work differently than each other.  You might want allowDrag=true, but useDamping=false.